# Finding exactly N consecutives in a sorted list

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11

I recently stumbled upon a little problem.

Part of an algorithm I was working on needed to find `n` consecutive numbers in a sorted list of numbers.

So, for example, the list would look something like this:

```
1 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 8 9 9 9 9
```

Given that list and N, the amount of consecutive duplicates, the algorithm needed to find the first number in the smallest group of exactly N consecutive numbers. So for example with N = 2 and the given list, the algorithm should find "2". With N = 3 it should pass the group of 2's, find the group of 5's instead since it's the smallest group of 3 consecutive duplicates in that list. It shouldn't return 9 since there are actually 4 consecutive 9's and with N = 3 we are looking for the smallest group of **exactly** 3 consecutives.

I did in the end cobble together some peace of crap code that did the job, but I was wondering how would some experienced programmer do this. Utilizing as much of the C++11 Style of Code [advertised by Stroustroup himself](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iWb_qi2-uI) and using as much of the C++11 STL for correctness, portability and compactness for reasoning.

Comment: Iterate through the list, checking that the ith element is the same as the (i + n)th element, but not the (i + n + 1)th element.

Comment: this helps ? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/adjacent_find/

Comment: Even though this is a rather small problem and you seem to have solved the problem already, please bear in mind StackOverflow is not a "coding service". There are probably a lot of ways an "experienced programmer" can do this, and possibly many of them only differ in taste; i.e. there's not *an answer* to your question, which makes it borderline off-topic. (As long as it doesn't attract bike-shed discussions, I won't down- or close-vote it.)

Comment: Do you have random access iterators? By "smallest group of exactly N consecutive numbers" do you mean the group with the lowest value?

Comment: N only states the size/length of the group, so with N=3 "4 4 4 4" would be wrong. "4 4 4" Could be right, if there's no other group with smaller values, like "2 2 2" and I was kinda hoping for a more C-Style kind of discussion. Stuff like whether to use std::vector or std::list for such kind of stuff because how about the list has 100k elements?

Comment: But doesn't 'equal_range' need a value that I'm looking for? I don't care for the value of the group as long as it's the smallest available. 'adjacent_find' doesn't help either if N > 2.

Comment: In terms of using C++11-specific functions, I'd probably rather stick to just a simple for-loop. Since you say you have working code, perhaps you want to go put it on [codereview.se] to have it reviewed instead.

Comment: I'm curious to know how your piece-of-crap (your words, not mine, but the self-deprecation is refreshing), handles `N=1`, since there are five values that seem to fulfill that manifest: `1,3,6,7,8`. In that case do you return the *first* one ?

Comment: @WhozCraig It does say "*smallest* group", so I guess it should return `1` ('smallest' here not referring to the number of elements, but rather the value). [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251965/finding-exactly-n-consecutives-in-a-sorted-list#comment30206975_20251965) re-enforces that notion.

Comment: @Dukeling and with that if there is no sequence of an *exact* count (though there may be sequences with `> N` instances) I suppose it simply returns ... something else. I can see why there are more questions than answers concerning the *actual* intended behavior. Interesting problem regardless.

Comment: @user2036087 vectors are notoriously not cheap in insertion, especially in pre C++11 standards, simply because a chunk of memory needs to copied/moved/created/allocated each time you insert a single element, and this is costly . a good alternative to the vectors, if you are having a lot of insertions is the std::deque , but in general std::vector are a good all-round data structure, they need a good allocation strategy ( a good allocator ) and a good use in terms of coding.

Comment: @DyP a solution based on equal_range will have complexity O(n*log(n)) while one can write a solution in a single iteration having the best possible complexity - `O(N)`. I think using standard algorithms here will only make the solution perform worse in terms of complexity.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Oops, for some reason, I thought `equal_range` required a sorted range, which would lead to O(n) complexity.

Comment: @DyP it does require a sorted range but it has a logarithmic complexity. A solution using equal_range will have `O(n*log(n))` complexity while the solution I propose in my answer below is linear.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev No, it requires a *partitioned* range. Therefore, you'd need a binary search, which leads to the logN complexity.

Comment: @DyP yes sorry I missed the addition in the documentation. Still my statement about the complexity is true.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev After some consideration, I think using `equal_range` wouldn't be worse than your linear variant. It isn't O(NlogN) I think, as every *range* is skipped in logM steps with the binary search, where M decreases by the size of the range skipped with each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed doesn't matter:

```
template <class T >
T firstOfN( std::vector<T> list, unsigned N ){
  std::multiset<T> mset( list.begin(), list.end() );
  for( typename std::multiset<T>::iterator it = mset.begin(); it != mset.end(); ++it ){
    if( mset.count( *it ) == N ) return *it;
  }
  throw std::exception();
}
```

Comment: Wow. That's AWESOME!! That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Great use of the STL, I didn't even know that a 'multiset' existed. The Code has great expressiveness once you understand the library functions and it just hits spot when it comes to compactness vs clarity. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

On the algorithmic side of things, there's an interesting optimization; pseudo-code:

```
size_t N;
RaIterator cur = myvector.begin(), end = myvector.end();
while(cur < end-(N-1))
{
    if(*cur == *(cur+N))
    {
        if(cur+N == end || *cur != *(cur+N+1))
            return {cur, cur+N};
        else
            cur = upper_bound(cur+N+1, end, *cur);
    }else
    {
        cur = lower_bound(cur, cur+N, *(cur+N));
    }
}
return {end, end};
```

If we have random-access iterators, we can skip ranges pretty quickly, once we have an initial element (preceding elements are smaller, succeeding greater or equal):

- If `*cur == *(cur+N)`, then the range with value `*cur` is large enough. If `*cur != *(cur+N+1)`, or `cur+N == end`, then it is indeed the range we're looking for. Else, it is too big, and we can search for the next range (either linearly or with a binary search in `[cur+N+1, end)`).
- Else, `*cur != *(cur+N)`, then the current range is too small. Every range completely inside `[cur, cur+N]` is also too small, so the next range to check is a range that starts inside `[cur, cur+N]` and extends beyond `cur+N`. This range is of the value `*(cur+N)`, so we only need to find its initial element (binary search).

Note: Due to the increased "complexity" of a binary search as opposed to a linear search (the constant factors), and due to the rather unpredictable memory accesses, this will probably be slower for a list of small ranges than the strictly linear approach.

Comment: Micro-optimization: `lower_bound(cur+1, cur+N, *(cur+N))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It does not use any stl standard algorithm but it has the best possible complexity - O(n) and I believe it is quite readable and understandable:

```
  unsigned cur_value_index = 0;
  unsigned range_size = 1;
  for (unsigned i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    if (a[i] == a[cur_value_index]) {
      range_size++;
    } else {
      if (range_size == N) {
        cout << cur_value_index << endl;
        break;
      }
      cur_value_index = i;
      range_size = 1;
    }
  }
```

if (range_size == N) {
        cout << cur_value_index << endl;
      }

I assume the sequence is provided in an array `a` and `N` is the limit you talk about in the question.

I have used vector for illustration but the very same algorithm can be applied if we don't have random access for instance for list. In that case we would keep an iterator to an element of the sequence instead of an index, but the rest would remain unchanged.

Comment: You have to search for a group of *exactly* N consecutive equal elements.

Comment: @ThomasAhle Quoting from the OP: "It shouldn't return 9 since there are actually 4 consecutive 9's and with N = 3 we are looking for the smallest group of exactly 3 consecutives."

Comment: You're right. Then you can just run Ivaylo's algorithm and stop once you find `N` and the next element is not another one.

Comment: @ThomasAhle I have fixed the solution. Thank you for the correction. I have missed this last bit of **exactly** N.

Answer (score 1):

A great deal here depends on frequency of insertion and deletion vs. searching, how large of lists you're looking at, etc.

For the moment, I'm going to make two assumptions:

1. You're dealing with large enough lists that an asymptotically better algorithm is likely to win over the obvious linear search.
2. You're doing a lot of queries with the data essentially static.

If that's true, you start by run-length encoding the input data, so you get value/count pairs.

Then you sort those pairs based primarily on the count, and secondarily on the value. Finally, use `std::lower_bound` to find a value, with the comparison based solely on the count.

This requires O(N log N) for the preprocessing. In exchange, each query requires O(log N) instead of O(N). Therefore, you need to do O(N) queries on the preprocessed data to justify the preprocessing.

Comment: For a sorted list, we can determine the frequency of each of the values in one pass, and store the results (prefer smaller over larger values) in a hashtable. Then pre-processing is O(n) and each query is O(1), right?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi: Yes, but that doesn't (directly) support the ordering of items with the same count, so you'd have to look up all items with the same count, then sort them an display the smallest. Could still be a win if the list contained enough unique items though.

Comment: you don't need the ordering of items, just take the smallest one. Since the elements are sorted, you don't have to do anything, just take the first one

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Sequence
{
public:
    Sequence(const uint32_t num_items);
    ~Sequence(){}

    bool operator()(const T data);
private:
    T m_value;
    uint32_t m_counter;
    uint32_t m_max;
};

template<class T>
Sequence<T>::Sequence(const uint32_t num_items)
  : m_value(0),
    m_counter(0),
    m_max(num_items)
{
}

template<class T>
bool Sequence<T>::operator()(const T data)
{
    if(m_value == data) {
        m_counter++;
    } else if(m_counter == m_max{
        m_value = data;
        m_counter = 0;
        return true;
    } else{
        m_value = data;
        m_counter = 0;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int data[] = {1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9};
    array<int,15> ar;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        ar[i] = data[i];

    //find three consecutive numbers
    Sequence<int> seq(3);

    //getting the first occurence of the sequence
    array<int,15>::iterator it = find_if(ar.begin(),ar.end(),seq);

    //printing the iterator position from begin
    cout << distance(ar.begin(),it) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although this code is not entirely correct, I really like the answer. THIS is what I was hoping for, not what the fastest algorithm would be. To me this seems to go in the direction Stroustroup is trying to push, away from writing C-like code like we did 20 years ago, on to to describing algorithms from a more abstract point of view (main() here), using as much STL/build-in language features as possible. Maybe we could use this as a reference for further discussion because that's what I wanted to know: How would Stroustroup write/express the algorithms mentioned here TODAY in modern C++.

Comment: Hopefully with the recent edit I've made, the code should now be correct (fixed the operator()(...) implementation and the display of iterator position).

Comment: I think the code is still incorrect because it finds groups that have at least N consecutives, not exactly N. For example if adding two more 2's to the group of 2's and setting N = 3 the code would find the group of 2's (although it actually contains 4 2's) and not the group of 5's containing exactly 3 5's.

Answer (score 1):

When N is larger, the detection of N same numbers might be "optimized" a bit.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - N + 1; ) {
    int ai = a[i]; // New value
    if (ai == a[i + N - 1]) { // Last element same
        if (i + N >= n || ai != a[i + N]) { // Thereafter not
            return i;
        }
        i += N; // Move to last known same element (or past end)
    }
    // Go to next new value:
    ++i;
    while (i < n - N + 1 && a[i] == ai) {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

It relies on having at the start of the for-loop a new value.